# Can anyone explain XSD versions

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio-2012, xsd

I am writing an XSD schema and C# code to read an XML file and verify it against the XSD:

```
XmlDocument myDocument = new XmlDocument();    
XmlReaderSettings xmlReaderSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
xmlReaderSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
xmlReaderSettings.Schemas.Add(null, "MyXsd.xsd");
using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("MyXml", xmlReaderSettings))
{
    myDocument.Load(xmlReader);
}
```

I'm not very experienced with XSD so I am referring to all sorts of web sites for help, but I keep coming across things like "This will work in XSD1.0 but not XSD1.1", or "with XSD2.0 do it this way". Can someone explain how I know or specify what version of XSD will be used. I'm using VS2012 - I don't even know if that is relevant.

Comment: See IEEE website : https://www.w3.org/standards/techs/xmlschema#w3c_all

Comment: @jdweng: W3C, but interesting to contemplate how XSD may have been different had it originated in IEEE.  ;-)

Comment: Isn't W3C a IEEE sub-committee?

Comment: @jdweng: No.  You may see joint working groups or activities in various areas, but they're separate organizations, and IEEE had nothing to do with XSD's development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commonly answers will state that XSD 1.1 is required in order express a constraint that requires [*assertions*](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions) or [*conditional type assignment*](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cTypeAlternative), but there are many other [**improvements from XSD 1.0 to 1.1 as well**](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#changes).

.NET only supports XSD 1.0.  Use Saxon for XSD 1.1 support in .NET (and in Java).

Comment: ".NET only supports XSD 1.0" - well that's that then! Thanks.